# Need to limit every odd or even thread with a semaphore c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

so I'm in a bit confused as to how I'm supposed to do something. I've got 5 threads that are doing a basic task and they are generated with a for loop in main. I've already used a semaphore that limits the amount of threads running at a time as that's a part of the exercise, what I've got left is to make sure that threads that are next to each other (they're numbered 0-4 using the loop) don't run simultaneously. What I've got as an idea is to block every odd or even thread(it doesn't really matter) but I can't figure out how to both let two threads in and at the same time block every odd one. Is there a specific method for that, or maybe if there is another way, like letting three in at first and somehow not letting the second one in but letting the third one. I'll leave what I've got done so far:

edit: For clarification the way it has to be thought about is actually a bit different then what I initially asked about. So if 1 is running both 0 and 2 aren't allowed to run. But if 0 is running both 4 and 1 aren't allowed to run either. I'm pretty sure that it's obvious that if 4 is running 0 and 3 aren't allowed to work etc. .

```
using System.Threading;

namespace StudentProblem
{
    public class StudentProblem
     {
         static Semaphore stop = new Semaphore(2,2);
         static Semaphore gate = new Semaphore(3,3);
         public static void Student(Object o)
        {
            
            var r = new Random();
            var num = (int) o;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Student " + num + " start learning.");
                Thread.Sleep(r.Next(2000, 3000));
                
                for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
                    Console.Write("_");
                //gate.WaitOne();
                stop.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine("> Student " + num + " start eating.");
                Thread.Sleep(r.Next(2000, 3000));
                
                for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
                    Console.Write("_");
                Console.WriteLine("< Student " + num + " stop eating");
                //gate.Release();
                stop.Release();
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var studentThreads = new Thread[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                studentThreads[i] = new Thread(StudentProblem.Student);
                studentThreads[i].Start(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use in your project semaphore slim ( built in c# )

Comment: yes I'm pretty sure it's allowed@zolty13

Comment: Let me get this right: If thread 0 is running, thread 1 isn't allowed to, but thread 2 is, and in turn thread 3 isn't, but thread 4 is allowed to run?

Comment: @MindSwipe yes, exactly

Comment: @MindSwipe Actaully I was not taking into account one of the clarifications in the problem. If 0 is running 4 is actually not allowed to run, since when you think about them in a circle 0 and 4 are right next to each other, my bad.

Comment: This looks an awful lot like the [Dining philosophers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem).

Comment: It is actually, I just googled it. Thanks! Good to know it's actual name and origin. Was quite fun to solve, but I'll have to dig in the actual way of solving it, mine kind of feels like cheating. @TheodorZoulias

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to ditch the whole multiple semaphore approach and went with the old and trusty way. I'll add my solution here. It's not that great, but it works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace testing
{
    
    public class StudentProblem
    {
        public static List<StudentProblem> allProblems = new List<StudentProblem>();
        static Semaphore eatingGate = new Semaphore(2, 2);
        private object id;
        private bool eating = false;
        public StudentProblem(object o)
        {
            
            id = o;
        }

        public object Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.id;
            }
        }

        public bool Eating
        {
            get
            {
                return this.eating;
            }
        }

        public void DoStuff()
        {
            var r = new Random();
            var num = (int)this.Id;

            Console.WriteLine(" Student " + num + " start learning.");
            Thread.Sleep(r.Next(2000, 3000));
            
            while (true)
            {
                

                for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
                    Console.Write("_");

                int indexBehind = 0;
                int indexFront = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < allProblems.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(num == 0)
                    {
                        indexBehind = 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        indexBehind = num - 1;
                    }

                    if(num == 4)
                    {
                        indexFront = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        indexFront = num + 1;
                    }
                    check:
                    if (allProblems[indexBehind].Eating != true && allProblems[indexFront].Eating != true)
                    {
                        if (eatingGate.WaitOne())
                        {
                            this.eating = true;
                            Thread.Sleep(250);//poigrai si s timeout-a
                            Console.WriteLine("> Student " + num + " start eating.");
                            Thread.Sleep(r.Next(1000, 2000));
                            
                            for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
                                Console.Write("_");

                            Console.WriteLine("< Student " + num + " stop eating");
                            
                            this.eating = false;
                            eatingGate.Release();
                            Console.WriteLine(" Student " + num + " start learning.");
                            Thread.Sleep(r.Next(2000, 3000));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            goto check;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        goto check;
                    }
                }          
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var studentThreads = new Thread[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                StudentProblem.allProblems.Add(new StudentProblem(i));
                studentThreads[i] = new Thread(StudentProblem.allProblems[i].DoStuff);
                studentThreads[i].Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```